# Estimate of $\frac{\cosh^2(x)}{\sinh^2(x)}-\frac{\cosh^2(y)}{\sinh^2(y)}$ depending on $x$ and $y$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, maxima-minima, upper-lower-bounds

Can we get any estimate of $\frac{\cosh^2(x)}{\sinh^2(x)}-\frac{\cosh^2(y)}{\sinh^2(y)}$ depending on $x$ and $y$, where $x, y$ real with $x>y.$

I have tried using increasing property of hyperbolics, get nothing.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Are $x$ and $y$ cloase to $0$ ? Is $y$ close to $x$ ?

Comment: yes, it may take value near zero.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps but, if $x,y \ge a > 0$, Lagrange's theorem gives you
$$
f(x)-f(y) = f'(\xi) (x-y), \quad \xi \in (x,y)
$$

which would yield
$$
\left|\frac{\cosh^2 x}{\sinh^2 x}-\frac{\cosh^2 y}{\sinh^2 y} \right| \leq 2 |\coth a | \textrm{csch}^2 a |x - y|
$$

Comment: Lagrange? I think this is simply the [Mean Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) (I was in the process of writing the same answer :) ).

Comment: I need entirely on $x, y$.

Comment: @420 just set $a=y$ in the above.

Comment: @Surb what I mean by entirely on $x,y$ is that on the right hand side of the inequality there would be no involvement of any function only bunch of $x,y$.

Comment: @Surb sorry about that. "any function" basically means get rid off hyperbolic(addition, subtraction,,, allowed)

Comment: @surb I call this result mean value theorem or Lagrange's theorem. Do you know any other meaning for Lagrange's theorem?

Comment: @PierreCarre For me the Lagrange theorem is in optimization (Lagrange multiplier etc.). But you are indeed correct, in the wikipedia article it is even stated "the Lagrange Mean Value Theorem".

Comment: @420 In the above expression $a$ is a constant smaller than $x,y$, so the inequality is of the form $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq k |x.y|$.

Comment: @420 ok, then [it seems that](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2Fx+-+%28d%2Fdx+cosh%5E2%28x%29%2Fsinh%5E2%28x%29%29) the bound in this answer can be upper bounded by $1/\min\{x,y\}$ so that you would get $... \leq \frac{|x-y|}{\min\{x,y\}}$.

Comment: @Surb if I take $x=0.5$ and $y=0.3$, then your estimate does not hold.

Answer (score 1):

If $y$ is close to $x$, you can use Taylor series and get
$$\coth ^2(x)-\coth ^2(y)=\sum_{n=1}^p a_n (y-x)^n+O\left((y-x)^{p+1}\right)$$ and the first coefficients will be
$$a_1=-2 \coth ^3(x)+2 \coth (x)$$
$$a_2=3 \coth ^4(x)-4 \coth ^2(x)+1$$
$$a_3=-4 \coth ^5(x)+\frac{20}{3} \coth ^3(x)-\frac{8 }{3}\coth (x)$$ and so on.